# untypical query, necessary index, optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization

```
select ip.ns, ip.u from iparts ip where ip.isF = 0 and ((ip.wl < ?1 and ip.wl > ?2) or (ip.wf = 0 and ip.c < ?1 and ip.c > ?2))
```

ip.isF = 0 - this part is the most selective, 95% of records has isF = 1, but this table will be really big

How to optimize this query?
Could you clarify which index I should add to table - iparts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following indexes should be helpful to your query:

```
(`isF`,`wl`)

(`isF`,`wf`,`c`)
```

Adding the SELECTed columns will improve it even further, making those indexes covering indexes, and so allow only the index to be used, without having to look up the main table.

```
(`isF`,`wl`,`ns`,`u`)

(`isF`,`wf`,`c`,`ns`,`u`)
```

The only downside to using this pair of indexes as opposed to the other pair is that insert time may be slightly slower due to the additional columns, and these indexes will take up more space.

I would also suggest a change in your query, in order to get the most out of these indexes.

```
SELECT ip.ns,
ip.u 
FROM iparts ip 
WHERE ip.isF = 0 
AND ip.wl < ?1 
AND ip.wl > ?2
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT ip.ns,
ip.u 
FROM iparts ip 
WHERE ip.isF = 0 
AND ip.wf = 0 
AND ip.c < ?1 
AND ip.c > ?2
```

By using a UNION, the RDBMS can make each query separately, using just the index appropriate for each query. If your data is guaranteed to have no duplicates between the two queries, you can change the UNION DISTINCT into UNION ALL and save even a little more time.

Note: You don't need both pairs of indexes. I suggest trying the first pair (the shorter ones) and see if the performance is acceptable (make sure to use my query.) If it isn't good enough, then drop those and add the second pair.

If you need more assistance, please add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE iparts` to your question. That will let us see existing indexes and column data types, both of which are relevant to any optimization.